# MySQL 8.0.3 defaults file missing in a running instance

Tags: mysql

Due to some configuration issue, I found out that I need to change a MySQL server parameter. However, MySQL was running in Windows "Services" as "C:\MySQL\bin\mysqld MySQL" which I understand does not provide a "defaults-file".

My question is,

1. Is there a default "defaults file" ? I searched for any *.ini or *.cfg file and could not find any.
2. Is there a sample file for this version I can download somewhere ? I tried some old files but there are some compatibility issues with previous versions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Download the installator of your version, install into virtual machine, take defaults file from the installation.

Comment: *Is there a default "defaults file" ?*  There is a lot of default files - different files for different server purposes. *Is there a sample file for this version I can download somewhere ?* I doubt. 8.0.3 is Release Candidate version.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. For admin ones try dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Server has "default defaults" built-in. No options file is necessary to get these defaults.

You can find all the default values for every option in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html

It's recommended to leave the defaults alone unless you have a specific reason to change one. Then make your own edits to your local options file.

It's a good idea to add comments to the options file so you have a record of why you changed each value away from its built-in default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Bill ! The real issue was that I could not get an export from my DB as default ''secure-file-priv" was a NULL. Eventually, I had to make my own config file as a flat server variables list does not work; they need to be categorized. Extra effort :/ but worked :)